# Can "be" verbs link clauses and/or a clause and a phrase?

Tags: phrases, verbs, clauses

Is this an example of a sentence where a *be* verb connects two clauses?

*You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing.*

Comment: "You are seeing ghosts" = Fact. This fact is the subject of the verb "be".

Comment: @Patrick D: Thanks. So, _be_here connects two clauses, right?

Comment: I can't term it otherwise ;) So, I'd say yes.

Comment: I think the part after _is_ is a phrase rather, but I am not sure.

Comment: You are seeing ghosts. Ghosts is what you are seeing, assuming 'ghosts' is a singular vision.

Comment: "You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing." or "You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing?" (it's not clear if the question mark is part of the sentence) is certainly unusual English; I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say. (If people are looking at video of themselves seeing ghosts, one might say "You seeing ghosts is what you are seeing", but I can't tell if that's the right context.)

Comment: Sometimes the repetition is used for emphasis or facetiousness, but one does not usually say "I am eating breakfast is what I am eating."

Comment: @Patrick D I believe "That you are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing" is the way to say that. I also find this cryptic, illogical, and informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really about the verb *be*.

> - *You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing.*

This sentence is grammatical, though odd enough to draw attention. That's the point. This is an extended [Cleft sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20cleft). Clefts of all sorts exist as a sort of syntactic polyploidy to magnify and amplify various parts of sentences.

For instance, the basic sentence all this is derived from is

- *You are seeing ghosts.*

A *Wh*-cleft of the basic sentence, focussing on *ghosts*, produces

- *What you are seeing is ghosts.*

An *It*-cleft of the basic sentence, focussing on *ghosts*, produces

- *It is ghosts that you are seeing.*

> (Clefts can also focus on other constituents, e.g,
>
> - *It's you that's seeing ghosts*
> - *What you're doing is seeing ghosts*)

In this case, the original sentence is simply re-inserted into its own Wh-cleft:

*[You are seeing ghosts]*  --*Wh*-->  *What you are seeing is [you are seeing ghosts].*

Answer (score -1):

Can the be verb link clauses and/or a clause and a phrase? The answer is 'yes'. In the example, "You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing." it has got two clauses: You are seeing ghosts - independent clause and 'what you are seeing' is dependent clause.

In the eyes of grammar the sentence is not incorrect, but such constructions are not very common. If we invert the clauses like, "What you are seeing is you are seeing ghosts." will be stranger than the first example.

If we change it as "What you are seeing is the sight of ghosts", it becomes a Simple Sentence (Sentence with a single clause) where Subject (noun) clause is "What you are seeing", verb is (the BE form), and complement 'the sight of ghosts".

Comment: Thanks @Ram Pillai for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Is *You are seeing ghosts is what you are seeing* a sentence you found somewhere? It doesn't sound right to me. I would rather express myself in this way

> Seeing ghosts is what you see.

But then again, it sounds clumsy because of the repetition of the verb 'to see'. Maybe it would be better to say

> Seeing ghosts is what you become aware of.

To go back to your original sentence, a more natural phrasing would also be

> You are seeing ghosts, *this* is what you are seeing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read it somewhere. Thanks for your answer! :)