# Sentence Structure analysis

Tags: syntactic-analysis

'The day we fret about the future is the day we leave our childhood behind.'
What type of sentence is it? Complex/Simple?? Kindly explain, Please.
Is its structure something like 'The day(when) we fret about the future is the day(when) we leave our childhood behind.'??
If it is, then why is it understood here?

Comment: Please check John Lawler's answer to this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553634/can-be-verbs-link-clauses-and-or-a-clause-and-a-phrase?r=SearchResults

Comment: It's a complex sentence because it has got one independent clause (The day... is the day.) and two dependent clauses ( 1. ...(when) we fret about future; 2. ...(when) we leave our childhood.

Comment: It's a complex sentence according to traditional grammar because it contains a main clause (the whole sentence) and two embedded subordinate clauses: [The day [we fret about the future] is the day [we leave our childhood behind]]. Outer brackets mark the main clause, inner brackets the subordinate clauses. The sub clauses are 'bare' relatives since the subordinator "that" is not present. Yes: they could be reformulated as _wh_ relatives by inserting "when".